# how to get inserted value from data base?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using mongo DB using express + node js .I inserted one value in Data base like that .

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.4
connecting to: localhost:27017/local
> use hockey
switched to db hockey
> db.playes.insert({
name:"naveen"
})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

I make **hocket** scehma name and **players** table name and add one entry  **name:"naveen"**..Which is successfully inserted .

Now I want to retrieve that value using connecting to mongo dB. I do like this

```
var express=require('express');
var app =express();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');


app.get('/app',function(req,res){

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log("Connected correctly to server.");
        db.close();
    });
})

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';


app.listen(3000,function(){
         console.log('server is runninngn')
})
```

when user type **http://localhost:3000/app** it gives {"name" :"naveen"}

Expected value

```
{"name" :"naveen"}
```

Comment: So it gives what you expect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to connect mongoDB to server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447819/how-to-connect-mongodb-to-server)

Comment: no ..it should give this ..it is not giving anything

Comment: Why would it return anything? You are not doing anything other than connecting to the server. You actually need to insert something and/or retrieve something. Nothing in this code is doing either of those things.